# El controlador no esta recibiendo los datos corectamente al enviarlos por ajax

Tags: ajax, mvc, .net-core

estoy escribiendo un programa que captura una lista de datos variables, la cual ingtento pasar a traves de jQuery a un controlador .Net core 6.0 MVC

El modelo de datos es este

```
namespace RTS_RecruiterSystem.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ScreeningViewModel
    {
        public int CandidateId { get; set; }
        public string TypeRequirement { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int ScreeningId { get; set; }
        public bool SelectedOption { get; set; }
    }
}
```

El controlador es este

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveScreening(List<ScreeningViewModel> lstScreeningViewModel)
{
  // Acciones
  return Json(new { success = true, message = "Cambios guardados correctamente" });
}
```

En el script tengo

```
$("#frmScreeningProcess").on("submit", function (e) {
    var lstScreeningViewModel = [];

    // Obtener el número de filas en la tabla
    var totalRows = $('#MustToHaveTable tr').length - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
        var candidateId = parseInt($("#ListCandidateScrViewModel_" + i + "__CandidateId").val());
        var typRequirement = $("#ListCandidateScrViewModel_" + i + "__TypeRequirement").val();
        var screeningId = parseInt($("#ListCandidateScrViewModel_" + i + "__ScreeningId").val());
        var selectedOption = $("#ListCandidateScrViewModel_" + i + "__SelectedOption").prop("checked");

        lstScreeningViewModel.push({
            CandidateId: candidateId,
            TypeRequirement: typeRequirement,
            ScreeningId: screeningId,
            SelectedOption: selectedOption
        });
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Candidate/SaveScreening",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ lstScreeningViewModel: lstScreeningViewModel } ),
        success: function (response) {
            // Maneja la respuesta del servidor
            if (response.success) {
                console.log("Datos actualizados correctamente");
            } else {
                alert("Error al guardar los cambios");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error en la solicitud AJAX");
        }
    });
});
```

Al hacer un debug, el arreglo que se envia por ajax al controlador tiene la informacion correcta:

```
[
    {"CandiateId": 1, "TypeRequirement": "M", "ScreeninigId": 1, "SelectedOption": true},
    {"CandiateId": 1, "TypeRequirement": "M", "ScreeninigId": 2, "SelectedOption": false},
    {"CandiateId": 1, "TypeRequirement": "M", "ScreeninigId": 3, "SelectedOption": true},
    {"CandiateId": 1, "TypeRequirement": "M", "ScreeninigId": 4, "SelectedOption": false},
    {"CandiateId": 1, "TypeRequirement": "M", "ScreeninigId": 5, "SelectedOption": true},
    {"CandiateId": 1, "TypeRequirement": "M", "ScreeninigId": 6, "SelectedOption": false}
]
```

El problema es que no logro que el controlador reciba los datos correctamente, ya que no recibe nada y no genera ningun error

Alguna sugerencia para resolver el problema

Comment: Saludos. El único detalle que observo en su código javascript es **CandiateId** del array de objectos/json que forma; del lado del servidor la propiedad de la clase es **CandidateId**. En el javascript le falta una **d**.

Comment: Gracias por la correcion RobertoLeOr, lo corregi esperando que funcionara, pero no funciono, seguire buscando la solucion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve tres dias investigando, haciendo pruebas de recomendaciones de varios foros, sugerencias de ChatGpt, pero no encontraba la respuesta, hasta que vi una publicacion de **sonicbabbler** en stackoverflow en ingles ([.Net Core AJAX Post Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777636/net-core-ajax-post-null)).
Ahi el problema era similar al mio, pero en ves de usar un objeto **`List<miModelo>`** usaba un **`IEnumerable<miModelo>`** y en la parte del ajax solo tenia un orden distinto de las propiedades **data**, **contentType** y **dataType**, pero en el modelo, todas las propiedades eran de tipo **string**, hice los cambios y funcionó.
Sin embargo, para mi era bastante frustrante haber intentado algo similar y que no funcinara, asi que regrese mi **modelo** a como lo tenia originalmente, a la accion del controlador le agregue **[FromBody]** y quedo asi:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveScreeningAjax([FromBody] List<ScreeningViewModel> lstScreeningViewModel)
{
    // Acciones
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Cambios guardados correctamente" });
}
```

Y finalmente el js quedo asi:

```
$("#frmScreeningProcess").on("submit", function (e) {
    var data = [];

    // Obtener el número de filas en la tabla
    var totalRows = $('#MustToHaveTable tr').length - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
        var candidateId = parseInt($("#ListCandidateScrViewModel_" + i + "__CandidateId").val());
        var typeRequirement = $("#ListCandidateScrViewModel_" + i + "__TypeRequirement").val();
        var screeningId = parseInt($("#ListCandidateScrViewModel_" + i + "__ScreeningId").val());
        var selectedOption = $("#ListCandidateScrViewModel_" + i + "__SelectedOption").prop("checked");

        data.push(
            {
                candidateId: candidateId,
                typeRequirement: typeRequirement,
                screeningId: screeningId,
                selectedOption: selectedOption
            }
        );
    };

    console.log("Array: " + data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Candidate/SaveScreeningAjax",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (response) {
            // Maneja la respuesta del servidor
            if (response.success) {
                // Actualiza la parte específica de la vista
                console.log("Datos actualizados correctamente");
            } else {
                // Maneja cualquier error si es necesario
                alert("Error al guardar los cambios");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            // Maneja errores de la solicitud AJAX
            alert("Error en la solicitud AJAX");
        }
    });
});
```

Lamento no poder dar una explicacion tecnica sobre como resolvi el problema, porque ni yo mismo se que solucionó el problema, pero como veo que este problema es muy común, espero y esto ayude a resolver este problema cuando a alguien mas se le presete.